# May the actual delay of setTimeout be shorter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) the actual delay of setTimeout may be longer than was asked. Could you please point me on documentation or question with answer which explains may the actual delay of setTimeout be shorter than was asked?

Thing is I encountered an issue which happened really seldom and could be explained by such phenomenon. Platforms: Chrome Version 67, NodeJS Version 9.8.0. Also, I am really curious is this statement true for Firefox and other browsers?

Answer (score 6):

You can test a timeout or interval accuracy by taking a delta of two microtimes. In my tests, the timers are plus *or minus* a few milliseconds. Run the program below to see the results in your own environment.

In a perfect world, the output would *always* show `1000`. The variance in the output means our world is imperfect

```js
var last = Date.now()
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var now = Date.now()
  var delta = now - last
  console.log(delta)
  last = now
}, 1000)

setTimeout(clearInterval, 10000, interval)
// 1000
// 1003
// 998
// 1002
// 999
// 1007
// 1001
// ...
```

To dramatically affect the result, press **Run**, switch to another tab, then come back to this tab after a few seconds. You'll see de-focused tabs have extremely high variance.

```
// 1004  <-- start experiment
// 997
// 1000  <-- switch to another tab
// 1533  <-- variance spikes immediately
// 866
// 1033
// 568   <-- switch back to this tab
// 1001  <-- variance restabilizes
// 1000
// 999
```

I don't know *all* of the things that play a role in affecting the accuracy of timeouts and intervals in JavaScript, but I also don't think that's an important thing to know. Ultimately we don't *need* accuracy because we can calculate precise durations of time using the delta technique above.

---

**a practical example in React**

Below we make a simple `Timer` component which naively uses `setInterval` to refresh the timer's display once per second...

```js
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props)
    this.state = { seconds: 0, timeout: null }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState ({
      timeout: setInterval (this.tick.bind(this), 1000)
    })
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount () {
    clearTimeout (this.timeout)
  }
  
  tick () {
    this.setState ({ seconds: this.state.seconds + 1 })
  }
  
  render () {
    return <div>Naive timer: {this.state.seconds}</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render
  ( <Timer />
  , document.getElementById ('timer')
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

But due to the unreliable nature of JavaScript's timers, we know that our Timer component will eventually display the incorrect value.

When we implement `PreciseTimer` below, we can use our delta technique to ensure the component always displays the correct duration

```js
class PreciseTimer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props)
    this.state = { start: Date.now (), seconds: 0, timeout: null }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState ({
      timeout: setInterval (this.tick.bind(this), 1000)
    })
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount () {
    clearTimeout (this.timeout)
  }
  
  tick () {
    const delta = Date.now () - this.state.start
    this.setState ({ seconds: delta / 1000 })
  }
  
  render () {
    return <div>Precise timer: {this.state.seconds}</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render
  ( <PreciseTimer />
  , document.getElementById ('timer')
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

To see the practical difference in how these two timers behave, start both of them, switch to a new tab for 10-15 seconds, then switch back to this tab. The naive `Timer` will suffer from JavaScript timer variance whereas `PreciseTimer` will always display the correct duration.

Comment: If you measure that the error is 10ms, just add 10ms to your timer and you're safe.

Comment: @RaphaMex no, that's not how it works. To get a better understanding, run the little experiment I described in an edit above

Comment: Yeah it seems that if it gets delayed (1705ms) it catches up with next run (366). How can we workaround this?

Comment: @RaphaMex *"it catches up with the next run"*, no it doesn't work like that either. Run a longer experiments to see that timeouts and intervals effectively guarantee nothing. *"How can we workaround this?"* – using deltas!

Comment: There is a kinda *catch up* happening. It's like setInterval goes on pushing callbacks in callback queue. When the tab gets focus back, event loop dequeues faster and does not respect the intervals. But I still miss the right explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually setTimeout will just push the callback on top of the event loop after the specified delay, but because Javascript is mono process if something block the event loop the callback will be delayed. But it can't be shorter or it's a bug in the code / javascript engine used.

Comment: What you write is right, but I think something happens when several setTimeout are run (say 1s and 2s), event loop is delayed, then the 2 callbacks are called in less than 1s.

Comment: Yes they are called in less than 1s but it's not because the second timeout is trigger before but it's the first timer that is delayed.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's single execution thread means that sometimes things that you queue up to be executed in the future at point x, might actually be executed on time x+, since there might be no execution-time-frame available.
However things will never be able to execute BEFORE the required time, only at-or-after your given time

A setTimeout(myFunc,100) for example may execute after 100 ms, or a little bit longer.
You can find more information on this article regarding javascrip's timers in general:https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: What you write is right, but I think something happens when several setTimeout are run (say 1s and 2s), event loop is delayed, then the 2 callbacks are called in less than 1s.

Comment: By performing tests, experience proves that the delay can actually be a little lower than the asked delay at least on some implementations. This has probably some explanation (like inaccuracy in the Date object, that's a possibility) but that's the truth. So no, you are factually wrong. setTimeout() *can trigger before the asked delay* (at least by measuring with the Date class and on some implementations).

Comment: This is the definition for the HTML 5 compliant browsers, you will notice that there is a default throttling of 4 ms under the hood, regardles of even defining 0 ms, and calling multiple setTimeouts.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting

Answer (score 1):

To complete [user633183's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912029/8122487), here is a timer that ensures your function **never runs before** given time interval:

```
class Timer {
    constructor() {
        this.last = Date.now();
        this.interval = null;
    }

    start (f, ms) {
        // Stop previous timer (if any)
        this.stop();
        // Start new timer
        this.interval = setInterval( () => {
            const now = Date.now();
            // Don't execute before given time interval
            if (now - this.last < ms)
                return;
            this.last = now;
            f();
        }, ms);
    }

    stop () {
        if (this.interval)
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.interval = null;
    }
}


const timer = new Timer();
timer.start( () => console.log(Date.now()), 1000);
```